# Проблема с кодировкой только в IE

Tags: php, кодировка, internet-explorer

Есть сайт весь в UTF-8, там есть форма поиска типа livesearch, запросы постоянно аяксом передаются на РНР скрипт. Во всех браузерах запрос приходит в нормальном виде, но только не в IE! Мне даже его (пришедшего в РНР скрипт запроса) кодировку не удалось выяснить и переконвектировать в РНР скрипте.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как заставить IE передавать данные из формы в UTF-8?

Comment: а в результирующих страничках в метатегах прописана кодировка? если да, то как именно.

Comment: Вот так вот:
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

Answer (score 1):

В корень сайта положить файл .htaccess и туда написать:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

Если не поможет, то заменить на строку:

```
AddDefaultCharset windows-1251
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавь любой юникодный символ в url.

Не получается найти ссылку, но со старыми IE была такая проблема. Кодировка 1252.

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте использовать кодировку windows-1251.

Comment: Не хотелось бы менять кодировку всего сайта и тем более БД!

Comment: Пробуйте для IE использовать другой шрифт.

Answer (score -2):

в результирующем файле пхп пропишите:

```
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=windows-1251");
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?